Salesforce Flow Input Validation
Need help to Write a regex in Flow input validation, which accepts Alphanumeric and space in between and maximum length 30.
I have tried REGEX({!INPUT_FIELDNAME},"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}$") It doesn't allow space in between.

What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] your question to add that information. Without that, your question is likely to receive downvotes and may be closed.

If you're not that familiar with regular expressions, this sounds like the perfect time to learn. The regex itself should be very simple.

@DerekF I have tried the above regex but I need it to allow spaces in between.

Whitespace is a thing that has a special representation in regex.
\s
The backslash is the "escape" symbol, it tells the regex engine that the next character has a special meaning. \s = space
So this may be as simple as adding that \s into the character class (the stuff between the [ and ]). Salesforce requires doubling of backslashes in Apex (and I think in formulas too), so instead of the\squick\sbrown\sfox you would need the\\squick\\sbrown\\sfox
If there's more rules you have about where the whitespace can occur, or if you want to say that the field needs to start with an alphanumeric character, then you'll need to put some more work into it. Sites like Regexr (no affiliation) are really nice for building regex.
